# Upload file to the specified path (OneDrive)?

Tags: ios, path, upload, onedrive

I prefer iOS code but the solutions in other languages may refer to this question too.

I use LiveSDK to access to OneDrive. [Here is a link to the example which uses upload action](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS/blob/5643c19e8615b76bf754308a96837c3f17314aea/examples/LiveSDKTestBed/LiveSDKTestBed/LiveServiceViewController.m) (onClickUploadButton:)

But I can't understand how to specify the custom upload path - only default `"me/skydrive"` works. How do you solve the problem when you need to upload a concrete file to a concrete path which may not exist? Should I create all the folders separately and/or get their `IDs` to place a file exactly into them?

Comment: What is "iOS code"? iOS is not a language. Do you mean Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: The functionality of the LiveSDK has been replaced by [Microsoft Graph](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/), I would highly recommend creating your application with it instead of the LiveSDK.  Look at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios/ for more details about a iOS native language SDK

Comment: maddy, both Swift and Objective-C are appropriate. The project is written on Objective-C but anyways I can convert Swift code into Objective-C.

Comment: Peter Nied, wait. What about this sdk? https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios
And anyways a half of the functionality is written on live sdk and I may have no time to rewrite it.